# php- script is sending garbage data even when no response is supposed to be sent

Tags: php, android, ios, json

I have a script that I use for uploading files to my server from an android device. It works perfectly fine except that the ios developer started having problems because he couldnt parse the response from the script as the iphone json parser complained about the garbage on the end of the response. in Android the parser doesnt care and works fine so in the debugged I looked and I found this

```
array(5){
```

on the end of my json response. Android just deals with it but ios tripps like a drunken sailor all over this little irregularity. So I got rid of the json response to the client and low and behold the response was still coming back to the phone even when I went through the entire script and removed every call to print.

So....my question is what would cause a php script to send a response even though it was never made to do so. Keep in mind that I went through line by line in my code and quadruple checked everything to make sure no response should be sent.

Comment: evil monkey!!, no seriously you want us to debug invisible code?

Comment: lol yeah i guess that would help huh....

Comment: Looks like someone forgot to remove a `print_r` or `var_dump` somewhere.

Comment: there is a little return() or echo() there somewhere... :)

Comment: GigaWatt you are the man lol I failed to realize the var_dump statement i had near the bottom of my script......I totally forgot that var_dump would do that :p dude make that an answer and you get the points fo show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've removed or commented out all `print_r` or `var_dump` statements.

Comment: lol thanks bro I had stumped myself with the invisible var_dump